# When div is clicked - slidetoggle other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slidetoggle

I have a problem with my jQuery code, I want the page to slideToggle one div ones the other is clicked, the problem is that I don't want to write all the code again and again so I tried to create a code that works all the time, but I'm stuck. Box is the div which should be clicked and it should contain a class that's also used on the div that's gonna slideToggle. It should pull the class from the tab and then use it to slideToggle the right object. Please help :S (the elements are not placed close to each other which makes next or children not possible). If you have any questions - ASK!

The jQuery code of mine:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
   var Klassen = $(this).attr("class");
   $("Klassen").slideToggle(300);
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- These should be clicked -->
       <div data-toggle-target="open1" class="box ft col-lg-3">
            <div class="mer">
                Läs mer
            </div>

            <div class="bild"><img src="images/sakerhet.jpg"></div>

            <h4>HöstlovsLAN</h4>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div data-toggle-target="open2" class="box st col-lg-3">
            <div class="mer">
                Läs mer
            </div>

            <div class="bild"><img src="images/sakerhet.jpg"></div>

            <h4>NyårsLAN</h4>
        </div>
        <div data-toggle-target="open3" class="box tt col-lg-3">
            <div class="mer">
                Läs mer
            </div>

            <div class="bild"><img src="images/sakerhet.jpg"></div>

            <h4>Säkerhet</h4>
        </div>
<!-- These should be toggled -->
        <div class="infobox" id="open1">
        <h1>HöstlovsLAN</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox" id="open2">
        <h1>NyårsLAN</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox" id="open3">
        <h1>Säkerhet</h1>
        </div>
```

EDIT - NEW PROBLEM - STILL AIN'T WORKING!

The code didn't work in my situation and would like you to take a look at the JS-fiddle I created: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Qqe89/

Comment: What is the class of div that must be toggled?

Comment: It should be the same as the box:s second class.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the html structure, including classes, that you're working with?

Comment: @TommieMichaelLagerroos classes are not ordered, so you cannot know which one is the second.

Comment: @sinsedrix true, but please check description for more. As I said it was only a test of mine, please share your solution so I can fix the problem :) Ain't that good at jQuery/JS

Comment: You haven't included jQuery library in the fiddle see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HycC3/1/ bootstrap js also depends on jQuery

Comment: @ArunPJohny Still not working even though I downloaded the file and it's declared in the head, `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <title>My Site</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>`

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny No errors...

Comment: Is script.js your script?  If it relies on jquery.countdown.js then try moving it to after that script call.

Comment: @TommieMichaelLagerroos add a log statement in the .box click function and check whether it is getting called? also make sure your code is inside dom ready handler

Comment: @ArunPJohny The problem was the dom ready handler, thanks for you help and good afternoon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

undefined has presented the solution.

I would warn you about using this approach, if you add any classes to the `.box` div then your code will break.

Instead consider using data attributes to target the div to be toggled:

```
<div data-toggle-target="open1" class="box green"></div>

<div id="open1">
    Opens
</div>
```

Which can then target with

```
$('.box').click(function (e) {
    $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).slideToggle(300);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZFuB/) with example using your html - crudely formatted sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").click(function() {
       var Klassen = $(this).attr("class");
       $("."+Klassen).slideToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. class attribute may contain several classes (`$(this).attr("class")` OR `this.className`)
2. `$("."+Klassen)` will not work if there are several classes
3. "Klassen" does not correspond to any DOM element as there is no such tag in HTML.